# Keeping track of an iterator through a nested xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to take the following input:

```
<test>
    <a>
        <b />
        <b />
    </a>
    <a>
        <b />
        <b />
    </a>
</test>
```

And create the following output using XSLT 2.0:

```
<items>
    <item num="1">
        <item num="2"/>
        <item num="3"/>
    </item>
    <item num="4">
        <item num="5"/>
        <item num="6"/>
    </item>
</items>
```

I know this is wrong, but for a starting point, here's my current XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="test">
    <items>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <item num="{position()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="b">
                    <item num="{position()}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </items>
</xsl:template>
```

This is clearly not the way to do it, because `position()` only considers elements in the same level. But how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <items><xsl:apply-templates/></items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a|b">
    <xsl:variable name="vNum">
      <xsl:number level="any" count="a|b"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <item num="{$vNum}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<test>
    <a>
        <b />
        <b />
    </a>
    <a>
        <b />
        <b />
    </a>
</test>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<items>
   <item num="1">
      <item num="2"/>
      <item num="3"/>
   </item>
   <item num="4">
      <item num="5"/>
      <item num="6"/>
   </item>
</items>
```

Comment: This is similar to the for-each solution that I responded to my own question with. Either will do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Webucator, You are welcome. The XSLT way of thinking favors `xsl:apply-templates` over `xsl:for-each` as the latter allows for polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2, using `xsl:number` is the right way, if your XSLT processor also supports XSLT 3, then using an accumulator https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-accumulator is an alternative:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="item-count"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="item-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="test" select="0"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="test/a | test/a/b" select="$value + 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="test">
      <items>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a | b">
      <item num="{accumulator-before('item-count')}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </item>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEvn

That would even work with streaming in Saxon EE where `xsl:number` is not supported:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="item-count" streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="item-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="test" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="test/a | test/a/b" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <items>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a | b">
        <item num="{accumulator-before('item-count')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution: use xsl:number with any level and counting both a and b:

```
<xsl:template match="test">
    <items>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <item>
                <xsl:attribute name="num">
                    <xsl:number level="any" count="a|b"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="b">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:attribute name="num">
                            <xsl:number level="any" count="a|b"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </items>
</xsl:template>
```